# Elixir: How to run tests with "mod" set inside mix.exs?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

In my `mix.exs` I have:

```
...
def application do
  [
    mod: {MyProject, []},
    extra_applications: [:logger]
  ]
end
...
```

I use the `mod` in order to execute my project (e.g.: `mix run myproject ARGS`). However, when I try to run `mix test`, it seems to execute `MyProject.start` with the parameter `test`.

If I comment out the `mod`-line inside `mix.exs`, `mix test` runs successfully.

Is there a way I can do both, run the project and run the tests without changing the `mix.exs`? Or do I need to run my tests differently?

Comment: Does your project define **an application** or not in the first place?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: I think so. I do have a `defmodule MyProject do use Application` and inside a `def start(_type, _args) do`. Testing some more, I think now, my issue was unrelated. However, I still wonder why `MyProject.start/2` is executed when doing a `mix test`...

Comment: `mix test` starts the application by default. You have to decide whether you want the application started for tests (usually you do, because most things deserving testing are usually not about unit testing,) but if not, you always can stop it with `Application.stop/1`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Thanks for the explanation. Sorry, I am too noob. Where would I need to call `Application.stop/1`?

Comment: E. g. in `test_helper.exs`.

Comment: I tried putting that in `test_helper` before or after the `ExUnit.start()`, yet `mix test` still ran the application. I might call it with the wrong parameter (I tried: `MyProject`, `:my_project`).

Comment: Ah, indeed, it’d start it after initialization. Then in [`setup_all/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup_all/1) callback.

Comment: I appreciate the help. But again, I was not able to run the test without execution of the application: I put the `setup_all` into the test-case execution `Application.stop(MyProject)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unrelated. I did not exit the application properly. Exiting the `def start(_type, _args) do` function with `{:ok, Kernel.self()}` makes the `mix test` run the tests.

Comment: [`Application.start/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#c:start/2) is a callback that implies you must return the expected value.